# PyPI rejects token authentication on upload from Windows

Tags: python, authentication, token, pypi

During an attempt to upload a python package to the testpypi repository with `py -m twine upload --verbose --repository testpypi dist/*` twine fails with the message,

> 403 Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See
> https://test.pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for more information.

The provided link states,

> If you’re using Windows and trying to paste your username, password,
> or token in the Command Prompt or PowerShell, Ctrl-V and Shift+Insert
> won’t work. Instead, you can use “Edit > Paste” from the window menu,
> or enable “Use Ctrl+Shift+C/V as Copy/Paste” in “Properties”. This is
> a known issue with Python’s getpass module

The package is built with PEP517 setuptools on Windows 10 Professional.  I have rebuilt the token in my account, copied the API token with the provided API copy button, pasted with the `Edit > Paste` menu item as specified, but twine still does not upload the package. So the `Edit > Paste` suggestion is not a solution.

How to do this from Windows?

Answer (score 2):

One approach that works is to paste the generated api token into a .pypirc file located in the $Home directory.  This file has with content:

```
[testpypi]
  username = __token__
  password = pypi-AgEN...fki6A

[pypi]
  username = __token__
  password = pypi-XcvB...aLd6
```

Where the password is copied from the generated api token.  One downside of this approach is that I don't see a syntax that allows for multiple tokens for a single server.